# Android C2DM: Could not verify SSL certificate javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, android, android-c2dm, sslhandshakeexception

I'm receiving the following SSLHandshakeException when trying to send a push notification through the C2DM servers.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Could not verify SSL certificate for: https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send
```

The code to send the message is as follows, and is running on App Engine. Everything works fine when I use cURL, so I know that the server authentication code and device registration ID are correct.

```
public static void sendHttpPostToC2dmService(String msg, PrintWriter out) {

    String authCode = "XXXX";
    String regID = "YYYY";

    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send");

        String data = URLEncoder.encode("registration_id", "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(regID, "UTF-8");
        data += "&"
                + URLEncoder.encode("Authorization: GoogleLogin auth",
                        "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(authCode, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("collapse_key", "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode("something", "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("data.message", "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(msg, "UTF-8");

        out.println("data=" + data);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                connection.getOutputStream());
        writer.write(data);
        writer.close();

        out.println("responseCode=" + connection.getResponseCode());

        if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String responseLine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    connection.getInputStream())).readLine();
            out.println("responseLine=" + responseLine);

        } else {
            // Server returned HTTP error code.
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        out.println("MalformedURL");
        out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        out.println("IOException");
        out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace(out);
    }

}
```

It seems like others have also had this problem, but I haven't been able to find a clear solution (at least not one I'm able to understand). Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `HttpsURLConnection` instead of `HttpURLConnection`.

AFAIK, `HttpURLConnection` doesn't verify hostnames.

Comment: Unfortunately App Engine does not support HttpsURLConnection. I tried using the technique described in [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/57ca5110e5cf5f6e), namely using java.net.URI prior to java.net.URL, but the SSLHandshakeException remains.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the testing phase, you could use the non-secure url to push a notification.

```
http://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send
```

I also got around this issue by adding a certificate validation callback to accept any certificate, but this was on a C# server. I'm sure there is a Java equivalent for this.

In production code you would want to verify the correct certificate or maybe just encrypt the data you are sending.